# setting up PC-Tracker

Tags: python, environment

I am trying to install [PC Tracker](https://pypi.org/project/pc-tracker/) in my windows environment.

I have installed all required packages mentioned in the documentation and I setup and activated the environment. My issue is, when I run `manage.py config` in the cmd with admin privilege, it shows the Python code instead of doing what is written in the documentation. How do I solve this?

My Python version is 3.10.5

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pc-tracker 0.0.1
pip        23.2.1
psutil     5.9.5
pynput     1.7.6
PySocks    1.7.1
pywin32    306
setuptools 68.2.2
six        1.16.0
wheel      0.41.2
```

These are the modules installed